# Update a target object using a source object

Tags: javascript, express, object, ecmascript-6

My problem is that I have a class "Product" which I use to create products and render them in my pages. This object has a constructor like this: `constructor(title, price, description, imageUrl, id)`, and I have a function to update an existing product taking its new props from the request body through a form in an "update product" page - a POST route then, like so (with express):

```
exports.postEditProduct = (req, res, next) => {
 const prodId = req.body.productId,
    updatedTitle = req.body.title,
    updatedPrice = req.body.price,
    updatedImageUrl = req.body.imageUrl,
    updatedDesc = req.body.description;

 const product = new Product(
    updatedTitle,
    updatedPrice,
    updatedDesc,
    updatedImageUrl,
    ObjectID(prodId) // I'm using mongodb!
); //rest of the code is just promise stuff...
```

Now, whenever I do something manually too many times, I like to think "what if I had a thousand of these"? What if my object had a thousand props to update? This is what I'm trying to solve! Using the variables where I take the updated props to pass on to the constructor in `const product` without naming every single one of them. Also, I know it's not cool to define variables like that, I was just messing around at this point, this won't go into production.

Comment: Maybe define your `Product` constructor so it takes the `req.body` object as a parameter, rather than separate parameters for each property.

Answer (score 0):

I would introduce the Factory Pattern which is used to initiate the instance of the class. With JavaScript, we are free to go with only function(s) which create an instance of Product rely on tons of different params.

```
const keys = ['title', 'price', ...]

function createProduct(params) {
  const product = new Product()
  for (let x in params) {
    if(params.hasOwnProperty(x) && keys.includes(x)) {
      product['any prefix' + x] = params[x]
    }
  }
  return product
}
```